# JQUERY $.POST to update SQL and reloading PHP script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html code below which basically pulling staff-status.php to the html.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <?php
    include '/sql/staff-status.php';
  ?>
</div>
```

I also have a script below to update mysql every 10 second.

```
 <script>
   setInterval("update()", 10000);
   function update() { 
     $.post("/sql/update.php");
   } 
 </script>
```

When I change the above script to include staff-update.php to reload every 10 seconds when update.php is done, it didn't work. I understand it has to do something with a callback function where you can include a callback in your code to reload the status-staff.php when update.php is done but I'm not familiar with the coding syntax. Can anyone help?

```
 <script>
   setInterval("update()", 10000);
   function update() { 
     $.post("/sql/update.php");
     $.post("/sql/status-staff.php");
   } 
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
$.post("/sql/update.php").then(function() {
      $.post("/sql/status-staff.php").then(function(html){ 
           $('.table-responsive').html(data)
      });
});
```

Comment: can you check in the network tab id the ajax is being hit & if yes then what response you are getting

Comment: According to the network tab, the "update.php" is firing but not the "status-staff.php".

Comment: Can you tell me which request is GET & which one is POST. As from your answer below, one is post & one is GET but in your question, both are POST

Answer (score 0):

So I got this to work by having them as two separate scripts:

```
<script>
   setInterval("update()", 10000);
   function update() { 
     $.post("/sql/update.php");
   } 
 </script>

<script>
    (function updateStafftable() {
      $.get('sql/staff-status.php', function(data) {
      // Now that we've completed the request schedule the next one.
        $('.table-responsive').html(data);
        setTimeout(updateStafftable, 10000);
      });
    })();
  </script>
```

Question is: how do I combine them into one? Having two scripts seem to be redundant and cumbersome for housekeeping.